# c# sql a linq (where)

Tags: c#, linq

Hola quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de hacer lo siguiente en linq

```
           if (Job != "") {
            Where += " AND Job LIKE '%" + Job + "%'";
        }

        if (Status != null) {
            Where += " AND Status = '" + Status + "'";
        }
        else {
            Where += " AND Status != 'Template'";
        }

        if (PartNumber != "") {
            Where += " AND Part_Number LIKE '%" + PartNumber + "%'";
        }


        string sql = @"SELECT Job, Part_Number, Status, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Order_Date, 103) AS Order_Date FROM Job " + Where + " ORDER BY Job";
```

Soy nuevo en esto de linq y la verdad no tengo idea de como seria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es aplicarle where a tu resultado en cada condición, para los like puedes usar el metodo Contains

ejemplo:

```
var results = (from Job in context.Jobs select Job).OrderByDescending(j => j.Job);
if (Job != "") {
 results=results.Where(j => j.Job.Contains(Job));
if (Status != null)
 results=results.Where(j=>j.Status ==Status);
else
 results=results.Where(j=> j.Status != 'Template'))
if (PartNumber != "")
 results=results.Where(j=>j.Part_Number.Contains(PartNumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer condicional

```
var result = from order in dbcontext.Orders
             where ((Job != "") || (order.Job.Contains(Job)))
                   && ((Status != "") || (order.Status == Status))
                   && ((Status == "") || (order.Status != "Template"))
                   && ((PartNumber != "") || (order.Part_Number == PartNumber))
             orderby order.Job
             select new {
                 order.Job, 
                 order.Part_Number, 
                 order.Status
             };
```

la idea es anular o no la aplicacion de ese filtro evaliando el valor que tiene la variable en el linq